# python multithreading synchronization

Tags: python, multithreading, synchronization

I am having a synchronization problem while threading with cPython. I have two files, I parse them and return the desired result. However, the code below acts strangely and returns three times instead of two plus doesn't return in the order I put them into queue. Here's the code:

```
import Queue
import threading
from HtmlDoc import Document

OUT_LIST = []

class Threader(threading.Thread):
    """
    Start threading
    """
    def __init__(self, queue, out_queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.out_queue = out_queue


    def run(self):
        while True:
            if self.queue.qsize() == 0: break

            path, host = self.queue.get()

            f = open(path, "r")
            source = f.read()
            f.close()

            self.out_queue.put((source, host))           
            self.queue.task_done()



class Processor(threading.Thread):
    """
    Process threading
    """
    def __init__(self, out_queue):
        self.out_queue = out_queue
        self.l_first = []
        self.f_append = self.l_first.append
        self.l_second = []
        self.s_append = self.l_second.append
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)


    def first(self, doc):
        # some code to to retrieve the text desired, this works 100% I tested it manually

    def second(self, doc):
        # some code to to retrieve the text desired, this works 100% I tested it manually

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if self.out_queue.qsize() == 0: break

            doc, host = self.out_queue.get()

            if host == "first":
                self.first(doc)
            elif host == "second":
                self.second(doc)

            OUT_LIST.extend(self.l_first + self.l_second)

            self.out_queue.task_done()


def main():

    queue = Queue.Queue()
    out_queue = Queue.Queue()

    queue.put(("...first.html", "first"))
    queue.put(("...second.html", "second"))

    qsize = queue.qsize()

    for i in range(qsize):
        t = Threader(queue, out_queue)
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()

    for i in range(qsize):
        dt = Processor(out_queue)
        dt.setDaemon(True)
        dt.start()

    queue.join()
    out_queue.join()

    print '<br />'.join(OUT_LIST)

main()
```

Now, when I print, I'd like to print the content of the "first" first of all and then the content of the "second". Can anyone help me?

NOTE: I am threading because actually I will have to connect more than 10 places at a time and retrieve its results. I believe that threading is the most appropriate way to accomplish such a task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am threading because actually I will have to connect more than 10 places at a time and retrieve its results. I believe that threading is the most appropriate way to accomplish such a task

Threading is actually one of the most error-prone ways to manage multiple concurrent connections. A more powerful, more debuggable approach is to use event-driven asynchronous networking, such as implemented by [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/). If you're interested in using this model, you might want to check out [this introduction](http://krondo.com/?page_id=1327).

Answer (score 1):

I dont share the same opinion that threading is the best way to do this (IMO some events/select mechanism would be better) but problem with your code could be in variables t and dt. You have the assignements in the cycle and object instances are to stored anywhere - so it may be possible that your new instance of Thread/Processor get deleted at the end of the each cycle.

It would be more clarified if you show us precise output of this code.

Answer (score 0):

1) You cannot control order of job completion. It depends on execution time, so to return results as you want you can create global dictionary with job objects, like job_results : {'first' : None, 'second' : None} and store results here, than you can fetch data on desired order

2) `self.first` and `self.second` should be cleared after each processed doc, else you will have duplicates in OUT_LIST

3) You may use multi-processing with subprocess module and put all result data to CSV files for example and them sort them as you wish.

Comment: I preffer multi-processes over multi-threading because of overkill with sync problems and possibility to have higher parallism level when you need to run script on several servers.

Comment: I/O bound threads are a lot less subject to the GIL and context switching. A thread consumes less resources than a process and in this case, this seems fine.